# how to post parameters

Tags: android, post, httpurlconnection

i have some code to send some string parameters via POST method to server
my code is this:

```
public int uploadAghahi(aghahi AghahiToSend) {

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        File sourceFile = new File(AghahiToSend.imagePath);

        if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

            prgDialog.dismiss();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                }
            });

            return 0;

        } else {
            try {
                JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
                params.put("mainsubjectid", "1");
                params.put("subsubjectid", "22");
                params.put("stateid", "144");
                params.put("cityid", "144");
                params.put("onvan", "سیاسیباسیباشیباشسیباسیبا");
                params.put("address", "سیاسیباسیباشیباشسیباسیبا");
                params.put("phone", "سیاسیباسیباشیباشسیباسیبا");
                params.put("email", "hseify69@gmail.com");
                params.put("tozihat", "سیاسیباسیباشیباشسیباسیبا");

                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                        sourceFile);
                URL url = new URL(ADDRESSsendAghahi);
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy

                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", AghahiToSend.imagePath);
                // conn.setRequestProperty("content-type",
                // "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
                        + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"obj\""
                        + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(params.toString());
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);


                // Json_Encoder encode=new Json_Encoder();
                // call to encode method and assigning response data to variable
                // 'data'
                // String data=encode.encod_to_json();
                // response of encoded data
                // System.out.println(data);

                // Adding Parameter filepath

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filepath\""
                        + lineEnd);
                // dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
                // + lineEnd);
                // dos.writeBytes("Content-Length: " + name.length() + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(AghahiToSend.imagePath); // mobile_no is String
                                                        // variable
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                // Adding Parameter media file(audio,video and image)

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                        + AghahiToSend.imagePath + "\"" + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                // create a buffer of maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }

                // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is));
                String line = "";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result += line;
                }
                Toast.makeText(AddAghahiActivity.this, serverResponseMessage,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                        }
                    });
                }

                // close the streams //
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                    }
                });
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                    }
                });
            }
            prgDialog.dismiss();
            return serverResponseCode;
        }
    }
```

i have a problem and it is with encoding Strings.
some of my strings are in persian and when send to server they get changet to other characters like below:

```
,3ED3ED3~'3E'3ED4
```

or

```
*G1'F
```

How can i send params correctlly?

Answer (score 0):

Find the appropriate encoding for the server, and encode your request with that encoding, and decode the response with that encoding too. For example, the code I did write yesterday on Python:

```
params = urllib.parse.urlencode({'tool': tool, 'input': full_text, 'token': token}).encode("UTF-8") # Encoding parameters
result = urllib.request.urlopen(api_url, params) # Making request
readed_result = result.read().decode("UTF-8") # Decoding response
```

The logic is the same in the Java too.

How to find appropriate encoding for server? Check http header for encoding.
For example:

[image]